# How do I directly display a man page?

Tags: man

I'm writing a man page for a program that I am packaging. How can I display the manpage file that I created, to check if it's all right? Is there a way to pass my file directly to the `man` command instead of having it search the installed manpages by name?

I tried doing things like `man myprog.1` and `man < myprog.1` but in both cases I got an error saying that the man page could not be found.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

`man` has an option to read a local file: `-l`

> -l, --local-file
>                 Activate  `local'  mode.  Format and display local manual files instead of searching through the system's manual
>   collection.
>                 Each manual page argument will be interpreted as an nroff source file in the correct format.  No cat file is  produced.  
>   If
>                 '-'  is listed as one of the arguments, input will be taken from stdin.  When this option is not used, and man fails to find
>                 the page required, before displaying the error message, it attempts to act as if this option was supplied, using the name as
>                 a filename and looking for an exact match.

So you can preview your work in progress with:

`man -l /path/to/manfile.1`

Comment: That's essentially Linux-specific.  You might want to limit your answer accordingly.

Comment: @ThomasDickey I only use Linux; you are welcome to edit or add an answer...

Answer (score 22):

The 'old school' way, for systems that pre-date the `-l` option, is

```
nroff -man filename | more -s
```

Answer (score 17):

I've used simply

```
man ./path/to/man.1
```

You need to include a slash in the path, otherwise it searches the system directories.
Works on the Linux and OS X systems I have (the latter doesn't have `-l`).

```
$ cd /tmp
$ cp /usr/share/man/man1/ls.1 .
$ man ls.1
No manual entry for ls.1
$ man ./ls.1     # works
```

Comment: This also works on NetBSD (I just tested it on NetBSD 9.3).

Answer (score 2):

On Solaris, the `-M` switch to `man` will override the search-path for manpages:-

```
man -M path/to/man myprog
```

Your manpage file must reside in an appropriate subdirectory corresponding to the section and mark-up language, eg: `path/to/man/man1/myprog.1` for an nroff-manpage in section 1.